# getClassLoader().getResource() in a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, classloader, getresource

I am in the process of developing an eclipse plugin. When I run my plugin a new project is created and I need to get a file from this project.

For this I used:

```
URL uri = TemplateCommun.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Identifiable.java");
```

However it is searching in my actual project and not the plugin's project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question as is. Am I right in understanding that your Eclipse plugin creates a new project? Where has Identifiable.java come from? Is it a class you've written? Is TemplateCommun a class in your plugin?

Comment: Yes my plugin generates a project that contains the class Identifiable.java. I need to verify if this class is really generated so i have to write code in the first project ( the one that creates the plugin) . 
My problem is I am trying to reach a class contained in another project and other workspace with getResource () and I couldn't make it.